# jQuery and Ajax request data issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with this code:

```
setInterval(function() {
        var timed = $("#chMsgCont").find(".chatMsg:last-child");
        var timee = timed.attr("data");
        $.ajax({
            url: "./ajax/checknew.php",
            data: {timestamp: timee},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#chMsgCont").append(data);
                if(data != null) {
                var div = $('#chMsgCont');
                var o = div.offset().top; 
                div.scrollTop( o + 12302012 );
                }
            }
        });
    },1000);
```

Even if data is null, `$("#chMsgCont)` scrolls down, why?

Comment: an empty string is not equal to null

Comment: Maybe data is just empty or undefined and not null so it will pass

Comment: may be data is a null string??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
if(data)
```

Or this way:

```
if(data != null && data != "")
```

Basically, `if(data)` is considered as data is false in these cases:

- data is "" or '' => empty string
- data is false
- data is null
- data is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`data` is just empty and not `null` (undefined) so it will pass, try returning something extra in your PHP file.

I prefer doing the following at PHP side:

```
/* suppose that i am evaluating an insert to my DB */
print(1); //if success

print(0); //if error
```

then at javascript side, do this:

```
if(data == 1) //means success
```

or just do the following if you are not evaluating something at PHP side:

```
if(data != null && data != '')
```